# Get mobile recharge plans of operators on android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where I need a list of recharge plans that the major operators offer. eg. paytm is an app that displays a list of plans.

Should I manually check for the plans and update them regularly or is there any API provided by these operators or is there any open source API that does it?

Comment: Here is the API http://www.paytmpayments.com/#seam

Comment: Is there any free one out there?

Comment: The best you can try is scrape the Mobile operator site pages and make your own data. Nobody will gave this rare information free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What country are you in? I am sure there are some APIs from third parties that allow you to get the specs of various plans.

Another way to do it would be to scrape the websites of the operators, or just maintain a list manually.

Comment: I am in India. I searched on google. I suppose I didn't use the right keywords.

Comment: There is already an app on the play store providing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Dataweave web site, they will provide recharge plan :
http://blog.dataweave.in/post/64192707157/dataweaves-telecom-recharge-plans-api

or as per @HansiHE suggest scrape the websites of the operators.